# grep when esc characters exist in a file

Tags: grep, escaping

I am trying to use grep to select some lines from a text file and later do some operations on it

When the file contains something like

```
Task [somedate] I_want:[this],Hz[100]
```

I can do something like

```
cat thefile.txt | grep "I_want:\[this\]" | grep -P '\[\d+\]'
```

to get the numbers.

However, the process I am running generated text files with escape characters

```
ESC[33mTask [somedate] I_want:[this],Hz:[ESC[31m100ESC[0m]
```

I think they were to give the color, not really sure.
I would like to process grep and extract the numbers (in the example the last "100")

How can I do that?

EDIT:

Related to this there is a similar situation [here](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/200169-esc-70g-m-characters-text-file.html). Same as there, when I do cat I don't see the escape characters but colorts. but with less the characters ESC are there. How can I get rid of them?

EDIT2:

Using `cat -v` gives me

```
^[[33mTask [somedate] I_want:[this],Hz:[^[[31m100^[[0m]
```

with that I suppose grep becomes simpler?

EDIT3:

I tried

```
cat -v thefile.txt |  grep "I_want:\[this\]" | sed $'s/[[0-9;]*m//g'
```

and I could get rid of *almost* all the unneeded things but not all

now I have

```
^Task [somedate] I_want:[this],Hz:[^100^]
```

but I am not able to get rid of those "^"s

EDIT4

I could finally do it with

```
cat -v thefile.txt |  grep "I_want:\[this\]" | sed $'s/\^[[0-9;]*m//g'
```

Comment: Share EDIT4 as an answer